# Chrome customization

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to edit the chrome live CSS file (*C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\GoogleChromeUser\DataDefaultUser\StyleSheetsCustom.css*).

Is there a way to edit one page's css properties?
In mozilla there is a way and it works fine:

```
@-moz-document domain("cnn.com"),domain("bbc.com") 
    {
        A:visited { color: #990000 ! important } 
    }
```

But this doesnt work in chrome. If I change the `@-moz-document...` line to `@-webkit-document...` it still doesent work.

Could you help me?

Comment: Sadly Chrome does not support it. Users have been asking for it, but there seems to be no progess yet.